# Batch-train word2vec in gensim with support of multiple workers

Tags: python, nlp, batch-processing, gensim, word2vec

**Context**

There exists severals questions about how to train `Word2Vec` using `gensim` with streamed data. Anyhow, these questions don't deal with the issue that streaming cannot use multiple workers since there is no array to split between threads.

Hence I wanted to create a generator providing such functionality for gensim. My results look like:

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec as w2v

#The data is stored in a python-list and unsplitted.
#It's too much data to store it splitted, so I have to do the split while streaming.
data = ['this is document one', 'this is document two', ...]

#Now the generator-class
import threading

class dataGenerator:
    """
    Generator for batch-tokenization.
    """

    def __init__(self, data: list, batch_size:int = 40):
        """Initialize generator and pass data."""

        self.data = data
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lock = threading.Lock()


    def __len__(self):
        """Get total number of batches."""
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.data) / float(self.batch_size)))


    def __iter__(self) -> list([]):
        """
        Iterator-wrapper for generator-functionality (since generators cannot be used directly).
        Allows for data-streaming.
        """
        for idx in range(len(self)):
            yield self[idx]


    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        #Make multithreading thread-safe
        with self.lock:

            # Returns current batch by slicing data.
            return [arr.split(" ") for arr in self.data[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]]


#And now do the training
model = w2v(
             sentences=dataGenerator(data),
             size=300,
             window=5,
             min_count=1,
             workers=4
            )
```

This results in the error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Since `dataGenerator(data)` would work if I'd just yield a single splitted document, I assume that gensims `word2vec` wraps the generator within an extra list. In this case the `__iter__` would look like:

```py
def __iter__(self) -> list:
    """
    Iterator-wrapper for generator-functionality (since generators cannot be used directly.
    Allows for data-streaming.
    """
    for text in self.data:
        yield text.split(" ")
```

Hence, my batch would also be wrapped resulting in something like `[[['this', '...'], ['this', '...']], [[...], [...]]]` (=> list of list of list) which cannot be processed by gensim.

**My question:**

*Can I "stream"-pass batches in order to use multiple workers?
How can I change my code accordingly?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was too impatient. I ran the streaming-function written above which processes only one document instead of a batch:

```py
def __iter__(self) -> list:
    """
    Iterator-wrapper for generator-functionality (since generators cannot be used directly.
    Allows for data-streaming.
    """
    for text in self.data:
        yield text.split(" ")
```

After starting the `w2v`-function it took about ten minutes until all cores were working correctly.

It seems that building the vocabulary does not support multiple cores and, hence, only one was used for this task. Presumably, it took so long because auf the corpus-size. After gensim built the vocab, all cores were used for the training.

So if you are running in this issue as well, maybe some patience will already help :)

Comment: Yes 1st vocabulary-scan is single-threaded. You can manually split this out, for clarity in logs/monitoring, by (1) instantiating model without supplying corpus; (2) calling `build_vocab()` supplying your corpus (single-threaded); (3) calling `train()`  supplying your corpus (multi-threaded). A simple iterable corpus that yields an item at a time will feed multiple threads acceptably  – the model itself uses 1 reader thread, that batches to many worker threads. Unfortunately due to Python GIL (etc) this only gets some parallelism, not saturating all cores. But recent gensim versions…

Comment: …can use an alternate `corpus_file` parameter (if your corpus is in a disk file with space-delimited tokens and newline-delimited texts) that lets multiple threads do their own IO into different ranges of the file - and thus is much better at saturating 8+ cores with 8+ worker threads (up to however many cores your have).

Comment: Wow this is a very detailled insight on my question, thanks a lot! If you write this in an answer I'll definitely mark it as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just want to reiterate that
[@gojomo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822292/batch-train-word2vec-in-gensim-with-support-of-multiple-workers#comment103929303_58822726) is the way to go: with a large corpus and multiple cpus, it's *much* faster to train gensim word2vec using the `corpus_file` parameter instead of `sentences`, as mentioned in [the docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec):

> - **corpus_file** *(str, optional)* – Path to a corpus file in [LineSentence](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence) format. You may use this argument instead of sentences to get performance boost. Only one of sentences or corpus_file arguments need to be passed (or none of them, in that case, the model is left uninitialized).

LineSentence format is basically just one sentence per line, with words space-separated. Plain text, .bz2 or gz.

Comment: Is there any way to have multiple of these LineSentence files?